# Is Eclipse content assist possible within jstl

Tags: eclipse, jsp

Is content assist possible in the follow scenerio in my jsp view?

```
    List products;
    products= dao.getProductList;
    request.setAttribute("products", products);
```

---

```
  <c:forEach var="product" items="${products}">
  <c:out value="${product. <-- is content assist here on the product model javabean??
```

I kind of think it is not because how would Eclipse know that I am working on `Product.java`?

Comment: Same problem, here.  Ever find anything that did this?

Comment: @MattMc I'm now using JSF, CDI and managed beans. #{product. and <c:out value="${product. both work, I believe, because of the Managed Beans/CDI annotations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this generally isn't possible. JSP EL is a dynamic language, Eclipse doesn't have the information it needs to perform auto-complete.

Comment: Thanks. I had a feeling it was no.

Comment: What if I define/declare a bean using `jsp:useBean` so that eclipse has information to do content assist?

Comment: @JohnS Did you ever find out if `jsp:useBean` works for this, or another method?

Answer (score 1):

You can try my plugin. It is available at : http://fast-code.sourceforge.net/. It is not as sweet as content assist but you can print field name of any class in a jsp without opening the class.

Answer (score 0):

The autocomplete can be enabled by adding jstl-api.jar to the classpath.